Power automate custom connector CLI create end up in Internal Server Error
[update: i managed to get the same swagger working via power automate portal -> create custom connector, so definition should be ok]
I'm following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/paconn-cli to create a custom connector for our flow. It's a simple azure functions app that has 2 http endpoints that do custom logic for us.
I can validate the swagger definition:
paconn validate --api-def apiDefinition-dev.json
apiDefinition-dev.json validated successfully.

my apiProperties.json looks like this:
{
    "properties": {
        "capabilities": [],
        "connectionParameters": {
            "projectGuid": {
                "type": "string",
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "constraints": {
                        "clearText": false,
                        "required": "true",
                        "tabIndex": 1
                    },
                    "description": "Guid of project",
                    "displayName": "PROJECTGUID",
                    "tooltip": "Robot automation state of this project will be set to completed"
                }
            },
            "apiKey": {
                "type": "securestring",
                "uiDefinition": {
                    "displayName": "Functions API key",
                    "tooltip": "Provide your functions api key for this environment",
                    "constraints": {
                        "tabIndex": 2,
                        "clearText": false,
                        "required": "true"
                    }
                }
            },
            "iconBrandColor": "#007EE6"
        }
    }
}

but when i try to create it, i always run into 500 internal server error with no details:
paconn create --api-prop apiProperties.json --api-def apiDefinition-dev.json
Please select an environment:
 [1] Development
 [2] Company Inc (default)
Please enter a choice [Default choice(1)]: 1
Environment selected: Development
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Encountered internal server error. The correlation Id is '40089457-bbed-4bb4-b4a6-53384358262f'."
  }
}
500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://api.powerapps.com/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis?api-version=2016-11-01&%24filter=environment%20eq%20%27062dbc0c-4132-ec5a-ae12-9ba72f6a5958%27

Anybody have experience with this?
